# I'm looking for a way to filter evenbrite events. But it brings me all the events. How can i filter them?

Tags: node.js, api, express, eventbrite

I have a problem to filter events in eventbrite api, it brings me all.
I already have the token and i know how to use it.

```
var request = require('request');
request({

  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.address=cordoba%20argentina',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer PERSONAL_OAUTH_TOKEN',

    'Content-Type': 'application/json'

  }}, function (error, response, body) {

  console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
  console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(response.headers));
  console.log('Response:', body);

});
```

I think that it brings me all the events of evenbrite

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problem in the HTTP request:

1. It should be `/v3/events/search?location.address=...`, not `/v3/events/search/?location.address=...`
2. The `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` header definition is incorrect -- it is a plain `GET` request, there is no JSON data in request body.